# Get Dagster Config Schema in Python

Tags: python, dagster

I am trying to programmatically kick off a Dagster job from my Python code. So far I am all set with using the python client to kick off a job with either the default or fully specified config.

The issue I am running into is not having the ability to ask Dagster what the config schema is. Is there a way to import the schema over API so that I don't need to hardcode it in?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to retrieve the config values you can use the following within the op/asset/resource definitions:

For an **op or asset**: `context.op_config["<config_name>"]`

Example for an `@op`:

```
@op(config_schema={"person_name": str})
def op_using_config(context):
    return f'hello {context.op_config["person_name"]}'
```

For a **resources**: `context.resource_config["<config_name>"]`

If you're looking to define the config values, you can do it in 3 ways; via Python code or via a YAML file. You can check the [official docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/configuration/config-schema#specifying-runtime-configuration) on it.